# get all the values ​of an item in the database and turn it into id

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a request form that selects the item in the database through select and creates a pdf through DOMPDF, I need select to pull the type and value values ​​along with the description to be able to inform them in the PDF, follow my file, I believe it is something like this

```
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col">

                                                      
<select name="productName[]" id="productName_1" class="form-control">';

 <?php
$result_cat_post = "SELECT * FROM itens ORDER BY descricao asc";
$resultado_cat_post = mysqli_query($conn, $result_cat_post);
while ($row_cat_post = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_cat_post)) {

echo '<option value="' . $row_cat_post['descricao'] . ':' . $row_cat_post['valor'] . ':' . $row_cat_post['tipo'] . '">' . $row_cat_post['descricao'] . '</option>';
}
?>

<?php
$result = $_POST['productName[]'];
$result_explode = explode(':', $result);              
echo '<label type="text" name="order_item_preco[]" id="order_item_preco_1" value= "'. $result_explode[1] .'"/></label>';
echo '<label type="text" name="order_item_tipo[]" id="order_item_tipo_1" value= "'. $result_explode[2] .'"/></label>';
?>
/select>
</div>
```

currently my code is pulling everything into a union value, so when I print the "productName" in DOMPDF it shows everything together instead of separately conform the image [enter image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EINL.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question with an explanation of what the script is currently doing and what isn't working.

Comment: its `$_POST['productName']`, which would be an array. learn to do basic debugging like `print_r($_POST)`, which shows whats in variables like arrays